# Trying to find all field starting with space

Tags: mysql, sql, database

My DB is acting a little weird and I figured out that `coin_id` of some products has a "space" as their first letter.  So instead of "123456" it is " 123456". I am trying to find all the `coin_id` that start with a "space" and then remove the spaces.

Comment: `UPDATE table_name SET coin_id=LTRIM(coin_id)`

Comment: @AbraCadaver Post as answer, so this question can be closed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to find them yourself, just trim them in an `UPDATE` query.  Use `LTRIM` or just `TRIM` if there shouldn't be leading or trailing spaces:

```
UPDATE table_name SET coin_id = LTRIM(coin_id)
```

As [Dudu Markovitz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6336479/dudu-markovitz) points out, especially if there are few to update of many, you can find them and update them for possibly better performance:

```
UPDATE table_name SET coin_id = LTRIM(coin_id) WHERE coin_id LIKE ' %'
```

Or for `TRIM`:

```
UPDATE table_name SET coin_id = TRIM(coin_id)
       WHERE coin_id LIKE ' %' OR coin_id LIKE '% '
```

Comment: Although logically equivalent, performance wise, it is not a good idea to update the whole set when you need to update only a part of it.

Answer (score 1):

Update has performance Implications.
Update only what you need to update.

```
update t
set    coin_id = ltrim(coin_id)
where  coin_id like ' %'
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?
Removing one character from the columns starting with a space

```
UPDATE table
    SET coin_id = RIGHT(coin_id,LENGTH(coin_id)-1)
    WHERE LEFT(coin_id,1) = ' ';
```

Comment: And if there is more than 1 space?

Comment: Replace `RIGHT(LENGTH(coin_id)-1)` with `ltrim(coin_id)` :D
Didn't know about the integrated `ltrim` or `trim` until now

Answer (score 0):

First, why is an id that consists of digits stored as a string?  Perhaps the "12345" is not really a representative value.

I would suggest that you use `like`:

```
update t
    set coin_id = trim(coin_id)
    where coin_id like ' %';
```

Notes:

- `like ' %'` allows the optimizer to use an index on `t(coin_id)`.
- The query uses `trim()`.  After spaces, at the end could also be a problem.
- If the value is digits, then it should be stored as a number of some sort.

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz . . . That is weird.  I don't even know what I might have been thinking.